# find image orientation in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm currently using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("img").each(function() {

        // Calculate aspect ratio and store it in HTML data- attribute
        var aspectRatio = jQuery(this).width()/jQuery(this).height();
        jQuery(this).data("aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);
               // Conditional statement

        if(aspectRatio > 1) {
            // Image is landscape

            jQuery( this ).addClass( "landscape" );

        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            // Image is portrait
            jQuery( this ).addClass( "portrait" );;
        } else {
            // Image is square
            jQuery( this ).addClass( "square" );;            
        }
    });
});
```

but it's just returning landscape every time.

All I want to do is have a class for portrait images so I can use CSS to make them 50% width and side-by-side, whilst the landscape images are 100% width.

Comment: You should `console.log` out the values of things like `jQuery(this).width()` and make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: Could you provide your html? At first glance I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Probaly cause the use of "this". Instead, use index,element on the each internal function, and then $(element).width()

`jQuery("img").each(function(index, element) {...
var aspectRatio = $(element).width()/$(element).height();`

Comment: @MerakMarey `$(this)` within an `.each( ... )` refers to the current iteration element.

Comment: OP, please provide a [minimal, complete, **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, your code works perfectly fine - [here it is copy+pasted into JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1vs25quw/1/). Consider ceejayoz's advice, and witheroux's answer - you may be trying to read the widths and heights of the images before they're loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't comment because reputation is too low, but I think your error might come from the fact that you're doing your `.each()` on `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`

`$(document).ready()` waits for DOM Manipulation to be safe but doesn't wait for all images and other content to be loaded.

`$(window).load()` waits for all content to be loaded before executing

They're most likely all coming out as landscape because they are short (only alt text height) but long (alt text width)

Comment: This is a very good answer: it explains the problem, explains exactly why it's happening, and explains how to fix it.  Nicely done.

Comment: THIS WAS IT!! witheroux thank you! Thanks so much for your explanation too, that makes perfect sense! I was scratching my head, as (as said in other comments) it worked in jsfiddle, but not on WordPress.  This was the exact answer I needed!

Comment: One problem, however - 4 images are loading correctly, but then every other image is 0 height. is there a way to run each time an image is loaded? I'm assuming this is a symptom of lazy loading or similar

Comment: Yes, instead of putting your calculation function inside the `$(window).load()` event, you can put them inside a `$(img).load()` event. This should trigger every time an image is loaded! If you're uncertain, you can always check the [docs](https://devdocs.io/jquery/load-event). I just noticed that .load() has been deprecated for a while and was removed in jQuery 3.0+. I would suggest changing any `$(window).load()` to `$(window).on('load', ...)`. Same for the img: `$(img).on('load', ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution working based on my comment. Instead of $.ready I used $(window).load to wait for the images to complete load. Also, in the .each loop I used index and element to avoid the use of "this". the main reason to do it is because is non descriptive, so, in large segments of code or nested loops the use of this can carry undesired effects.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    jQuery("img").each(function(index, element) {

        // Calculate aspect ratio and store it in HTML data- attribute
        var aspectRatio = $(element).width()/$(element).height();
        $(element).data("aspect-ratio", aspectRatio);
               // Conditional statement

        if(aspectRatio > 1) {
            // Image is landscape

            $(element).addClass( "landscape" );

        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            // Image is portrait
            $(element).addClass( "portrait" );;
        } else {
            // Image is square
            $(element).addClass( "square" );;            
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: This is identical to OP's code. `$(element)` and `$(this)` are exactly the same. The question does not show us the issue, as OP's code [works fine as it is](http://jsfiddle.net/1vs25quw/1/).

Comment: I understand the question quite clearly. Please take a second to understand my point: Your code and OP's code **are identical**. If you visit the link in my previous comment (which is OP's code *copy+pasted*), it *works*. I'm telling you that you haven't provided a *solution* or explained the issue with OP's example - you've merely re-written it in a very, very slightly different way. If you truly believe you've solved the issue, your answer should **explain** why changing just 2 out of 6 references of `$(this)` to `$(element)` was the solution, as opposed to just *"Hey, do this."*

Comment: I see you've now changed your `$(document).ready( ... )` to `$(window).load( ... )`, which I believe is now on the right track, so I've removed my downvote. That said, you should provide some context as to what you've changed and *why* you've changed it, so that OP doesn't have to play a game of spot-the-difference. Also, personally, I think having references to both `$(this)` *and* `$(element)` in the same block seems strange, but given that it doesn't provide a functional difference, I suppose it's personal preference.

Comment: I stand corrected. I left out the change for $(window).load(). But still, before downvoting, ask, so the person can correct the solution and evolve in a more constructive way. Downvoting without communication is just repression, and not a very productive solution.

Comment: Duly noted. I will keep adding the explanation for the OP and for future users. Thanks for removing the downvote. Unfortunately i don't see a way to remove the flag. Do you know how?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but no worries. For future reference, I advise against flagging people for downvotes, as you can't possibly know *who* downvoted you. In many cases if I see an answer downvoted without any reason, I feel bad for the answerer, and I try my best to provide a reason and help them towards correcting their answer. Unfortunately, this results in many people thinking that *I* downvoted their answer, and taking out their frustrations on me. That all said, i'm not reprimanding, just providing some simple advice. I appreciate you understanding and correcting your answer!

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you Tyler!. I'm recently new to SO as you can see, and unfortunately I have already been victim of anonymous downvotes. My opinion, downvoting should be conditioned to a reason. If its constructive criticism I can handle anything that comes my way, we are all here to learn and truly believe downvoting would not be that bad if there is an explanation on why. Anyway, I also added some comments and background explanations. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're going to replace `this` with `element`, can you please do it throughout the whole function, instead of just doing it a couple times and leaving the rest as is?  (Personally I see no reason to make that change, but if you're going to do it, doing it halfway is worse than not at all.)

Comment: @DanielBeck Excellent observation. I just updated the code.